# rails 5 spree 3.2 volume pricing extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, spree

I'm trying to install the volume pricing extension and it has been painful. I havent found much on this error and I don't know how to access the file in the error. Any help would eb much appreciated.

> rails generate spree_volume_pricing:install

```
/Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/assertions.rb:18:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type, :index_errors (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/assertions.rb:16:in `each_key'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/assertions.rb:16:in `assert_valid_keys'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:78:in `validate_options'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:44:in `create_reflection'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:29:in `build'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1365:in `has_many'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/spree_volume_pricing-e55ebaf35575/app/models/spree/variant_decorator.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/spree_volume_pricing-e55ebaf35575/app/models/spree/variant_decorator.rb:1:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/spree_volume_pricing-e55ebaf35575/app/models/spree/variant_decorator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/spree_volume_pricing-e55ebaf35575/lib/spree_volume_pricing/engine.rb:5:in `block in activate'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/spree_volume_pricing-e55ebaf35575/lib/spree_volume_pricing/engine.rb:4:in `glob'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/spree_volume_pricing-e55ebaf35575/lib/spree_volume_pricing/engine.rb:4:in `activate'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:87:in `prepare!'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/Desktop/rails/sticker_cove/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/danielhatcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `state-machines` version (0.4.0) is [2 years old](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines/tree/v0.4.0) and your `spree_volume_pricing` commit (e55ebaf35575) is [5 years old](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_volume_pricing/commit/e55ebaf35575). With those conditions is nearly impossible they worked with `rails` version 5.0.3 which was released only [16 days ago](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/52780d5d66515b3d9e5d10d2975deda3699ffd88).
From that position, I guess your options are:

- Downgrade rails to a version compatible with those gem versions.
- Using master branches for your gems and cross your fingers that those versions at least be compatible with rails 5.x (last commit for spree_volume_pricing was May 13 2016) :

  ```
  gem 'state_machines', github: 'state-machines/state_machines', branch: :master
  gem 'spree_volume_pricing', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_volume_pricing', branch: :master
  ```
- Change to gems with better support from community. Instead of `state_machines` you could use [`aasm`](https://github.com/aasm/aasm). No idea about a replacement for `spree_volume_pricing`.
- Contribute to the development of those gems and make them compatible with rails 5.

Good luck with that